# Arduino Serial.read doesn't work

Tags: arduino, serial-port, atmega

My Arduino Mega (with CH340 but all the drivers needed installed) has stopped reading from the serial port. Doesn´t matter what I write it keeps saving number 50. I have tried with simple examples codes as this one:

```
int incomingByte = 0;   // for incoming serial data

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);     // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
}

void loop() {

    // send data only when you receive data:
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        // read the incoming byte:
        incomingByte = Serial.read();

        // say what you got:
        Serial.print("I received: ");
        Serial.println(incomingByte, DEC);
    }
}
```

And I get the same response.
The arduino has been working fine untill today. `Serial.print()` works also fine, it's just `Serial.read()` Anyone knows what the problem could be?? I haven't found much help on the internet, seems I am the first one dealing with this issue.

Comment: The first line of your example program isn't formatted as code. I just tried it out and it works correctly for me. So no matter what you enter in the Serial Monitor the Arduino prints "I received: 50"? Never any other number?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found what my problem was. Don't know if it was Serial.read or Serial println / Serial.write, some of these functions were converting from integers to chars, so numbers appeared to be only between 49 and 58. Using Serial.print instead it works perfectly. Thanks for the answers by the way.